# Python FlaskKafka - Exception on the thread of the bus kills the thread, and I have to restart application

Tags: python, flask, kafka-consumer-api

What is the best way of going around this?
If I run into an exception on the thread of the "bus" (FlaskKafka consumer) the bus stops and the only way to get it to start back up is to restart my application.